# C# DataTable Update string Column with format exeption

Tags: c#, string, oracle, datatable

If in a datatable a string value is to be changed, then this leads to a format exception, if the same value is written then not.

The problem is caused when importing CSV files when string columns change.

CSV File import Lines with ISO-8859-1

```
Original import
|  09.07.2019 |1234567890     |Dies ist ein Test   |          20|Change äü     |01.08.2019|

Update import
|  09.07.2019 |1234567890     |This is a Test   |          20|Final      |03.08.2019|

string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileNameFull, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Import first File into a DataTable connect with OracleConnection and OracleDataAdapter (dotConnect for Oracle)

The Import works fine

```
string[] import_columns = Lines[line_number].Split('|').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToArray();
DataRow current_row= target_table.NewRow();
//abbreviated code for each column, the following is executed
try
{
    switch (target_table.Columns[column_name].DataType.Name)
    {
        case "String":
            current_row[column_name] = import_columns[column_index];
            break;

       //pruned
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(column_name+ " : " + target_table.Columns[column_name].DataType.Name + " => " + import_columns[column_index].ToString() + " ### " + ex.Message);
    //throw;
}
// after last Column
target_table.Rows.Add(current_row);
```

But the Update with the new File generate an Format Exception for all change String Values

```
string[] import_columns = Lines[line_number].Split('|').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToArray();
DataRow current_row = FindRow(target_table, import_columns);
current_row.BeginEdit();
//abbreviated code for each column, the following is executed
try
{
    switch (target_table.Columns[column_name].DataType.Name)
    {
        case "String":
            current_row[column_name] = import_columns[column_index];
            break;

       //pruned
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(column_name+ " : " + target_table.Columns[column_name].DataType.Name + " => " + import_columns[column_index].ToString() + " ### " + ex.Message);
    //throw;
}
// after last Column
current_row.EndEdit();
```

Comment: The CSV file is using '|" character to separate columns and the old code uses : string[] import_columns = Lines[line_number].Split('|').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToArray();.  The new code is not splitting the columns.

Comment: Im Update Teil habe ich im Beispiel die Zeile vergessen einzutragen, im Originalcode sind beide Codefragmente identisch

Comment: Does the CSV have a header row?  Are you using the first row as the column names?  If the first row of the two files are different and you are using the first row as the names you will have an issue.

Comment: The error only occurs if a string value is to be overwritten with a different value!

Example current_row[2] has the content "test" if I write there current_row[2]="test" it works.
But if I write current_row[2]="hello" there is an exception.
It doesn't matter if they are imported from the CSV file or if I overwrite all string columns with e.g. "hello"!

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Something else is happening that is not obvious.

Comment: The error could be found, it was not due to the process shown here, but to the method for the DataColumnChangeEventHandler.
This method was not yet complete and caused the format exception, which was caught in the upper part of the code.